# Aplicacion de c# conectada a sql server de manera remota

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Ya acabe mi aplicación y ahora me quiero conectar de manera remota a mi base de datos, que esta alojada en una maquina virtual y la app la debo instalar en 6 maquinas diferentes dentro de la misma red; pero no me permite acceder ya habilite el protocolo *TCP/IP* en el *configuration manager* y permite acceso remoto en SQL, pero aun así no me permite.

¿en que estoy fallando?

Abajo mi código

```
Cadena.ConnectionString = "Password=anonim" + ";Persist Security Info=True" + ";User ID=anonim" + ";Initial Catalog=Proyectoanonim" + ";Data Source= 19 *. * * .* * * . * * * (ip)";
```

Comment: Que versión de .NET usas? y usas algún ORM?

Comment: Si tienes un SQL Server Express, deberás indicar el nombre de la instancia, del modo `Data Source= 19 *. * * .* * * . * * * \NombreInstancia. Por defecto suele ser `\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: @RogerTorné es SQL Server Managment Studio

Comment: @BrianJerezBaez NET Framework 4.8

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje de error específico estás viendo?

Comment: el servidor virtual tiene acceso externo?? esto puede ser desde un firewall hasta cualquier cosa...

Comment: creo que no, es probable que sea eso? -@gbianchi